# Highsoft.Highstock .NET - How to update navigation on all charts with MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, highcharts

I am using Highsoft.Highstock .NET on my ASP.net MVC 5 application.

I create a list of single line charts directly inside the controller and send all the data to the view.

When I change the navigation (start/enddate slider at the bottom of the chart) for one chart, I would like to update all other charts to the same timeframe (all charts have the same timespan).

I would like to do this with jquery, but I am not able right now.
I think I have to use the

(I was also reading the API from Highstock but there is something different, e.g.: my charts do not have a property "chart.title.text" -> my one has   "chart.title.textStr")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JS solution:**

To update all charts when you change the navigator position on one of them you can use `xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes` event to set new extremes on all charts (you can find all charts reference in `Highcharts.charts` array).

**Code:**

```
var json = "[[1534512600000,217.58],[1534771800000,215.46],[1534858200000,215.04],[1534944600000,215.05],[1535031000000,215.49],[1535117400000,216.16],[1535376600000,217.94],[1535463000000,219.7],[1535549400000,222.98],[1535635800000,225.03],[1535722200000,227.63],[1536067800000,228.36],[1536154200000,226.87],[1536240600000,223.1],[1536327000000,221.3],[1536586200000,218.33],[1536672600000,223.85],[1536759000000,221.07],[1536845400000,226.41],[1536931800000,223.84],[1537191000000,217.88],[1537277400000,218.24],[1537363800000,218.37],[1537450200000,220.03],[1537536600000,217.66],[1537795800000,220.79],[1537882200000,222.19],[1537968600000,220.42],[1538055000000,224.95],[1538141400000,225.74],[1538400600000,227.26],[1538487000000,229.28],[1538573400000,232.07],[1538659800000,227.99],[1538746200000,224.29],[1539005400000,223.77],[1539091800000,226.87],[1539178200000,216.36],[1539264600000,214.45],[1539351000000,222.11],[1539610200000,217.36],[1539696600000,222.15],[1539783000000,221.19],[1539869400000,216.02],[1539955800000,219.31],[1540215000000,220.65],[1540301400000,222.73],[1540387800000,215.09],[1540474200000,219.8],[1540560600000,216.3],[1540819800000,212.24],[1540906200000,213.3],[1540992600000,218.86],[1541079000000,222.22],[1541165400000,207.48],[1541428200000,201.59],[1541514600000,203.77],[1541601000000,209.95],[1541687400000,208.49],[1541773800000,204.47],[1542033000000,194.17],[1542119400000,192.23],[1542205800000,186.8],[1542292200000,191.41],[1542378600000,193.53],[1542637800000,185.86],[1542724200000,176.98],[1542810600000,176.78],[1542983400000,172.29],[1543242600000,174.62],[1543329000000,174.24],[1543415400000,180.94],[1543501800000,179.55],[1543588200000,178.58],[1543847400000,184.82],[1543933800000,176.69],[1544106600000,174.72],[1544193000000,168.49],[1544452200000,169.6],[1544538600000,168.63],[1544625000000,169.1],[1544711400000,170.95],[1544797800000,165.48],[1545057000000,163.94],[1545143400000,166.07],[1545229800000,160.89],[1545316200000,156.83],[1545402600000,150.73],[1545661800000,146.83],[1545834600000,157.17],[1545921000000,156.15],[1546007400000,156.23],[1546266600000,157.74],[1546439400000,157.92],[1546525800000,142.19],[1546612200000,148.26],[1546871400000,147.93],[1546957800000,150.75],[1547044200000,153.31],[1547130600000,153.8]]";

var data = JSON.parse(json);

function updateExtremes() {
  var currentChart = this.chart,
    chartIndex = currentChart.index,
    charts = Highcharts.charts,
    min = currentChart.xAxis[0].min,
    max = currentChart.xAxis[0].max;

  charts.forEach(function(chart) {
    if (chart.index !== chartIndex) {
      chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max, true, false);
    }
  });
}

Highcharts.stockChart('container1', {
  chart: {
    height: 250
  },
  rangeSelector: {
    selected: 0
  },
  title: {
    text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
  },
  xAxis: {
    events: {
      afterSetExtremes: function() {
        updateExtremes.call(this);
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'AAPL',
    data: data,
    tooltip: {
      valueDecimals: 2
    }
  }]
});

Highcharts.stockChart('container2', {
  chart: {
    height: 250
  },
  rangeSelector: {
    selected: 0
  },
  title: {
    text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
  },
  xAxis: {
    events: {
      afterSetExtremes: function() {
        updateExtremes.call(this);
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'AAPL',
    data: data,
    tooltip: {
      valueDecimals: 2
    }
  }]
});

Highcharts.stockChart('container3', {
  chart: {
    height: 250
  },
  rangeSelector: {
    selected: 0
  },
  title: {
    text: 'AAPL Stock Price'
  },
  xAxis: {
    events: {
      afterSetExtremes: function() {
        updateExtremes.call(this);
      }
    }
  },
  series: [{
    name: 'AAPL',
    data: data,
    tooltip: {
      valueDecimals: 2
    }
  }]
});
```

**Demo:** 
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/74rgyq13/

**JS API reference:** 
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.events.afterSetExtremes 
https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes

**C# API reference:** 
http://dotnet.highcharts.com/Help/Highcharts/html/class_highsoft_1_1_web_1_1_mvc_1_1_charts_1_1_x_axis_events.html#aa8efb1a8237bc71a0268e5ee7e522096 
http://dotnet.highcharts.com/Help/Highcharts/html/class_highsoft_1_1_web_1_1_mvc_1_1_charts_1_1_x_axis_events.html#a120bc76164638d4a76a7ee20280d54ff

Comment: Hello, thank you for the answer and the JS solution.

Comment: But as you probably kown my whole chart comes from an asp.net mvc controller. Do you have an idea how to assign the:
  xAxis: {
    events: {
      afterSetExtremes: function() {
        updateExtremes.call(this);
      }
    }
  }
 to an outside of JS created chart or maybe how to pass the:
   function() {
        updateExtremes.call(this);
      }
  Already from the controller together with the rest of the chart...

Comment: The function `updateExtremes()` should be written in a view file. Whereas invocation has to be a string like that: `afterSetExtremes="function(){updateExtremes.call(this);}"`.